# Android Studio firebase get key of child with specific value

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have am developing an app in Android Studio and I am using FireBase to store data. Lets say I have a node that has multiple children, I would like to get the key of the child that has a specific value. For example;

[image]

I would like to read from the node 'languages', the key of the child with value 'English' so that I get 'eng'. Note that upfront I do not know that the key is 'eng'!

Someone knows a way to achieve this, without importing all the children?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("languages");

        ref.orderByValue().equalTo("English").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot snap : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String value = snap.getValue(String.class);
                    String key = snap.getKey();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Oh wow thank you, I was not able to find this anywhere else. The reason for the loop is just for if there are multiple children with value 'English' right?

Comment: exactly, a query always returns all possible locations so in the case it might have more then one location you can get it in the loop

Comment: Great answer Levi! The reason for the loop is indeed that a query may match multiple results, so it returns a list of matches. Even if there's only a single match, the result is a list of one. So you'll always need the loop, even if there's only one answer.

Comment: Thank you @Frank van Puffelen :)

Comment: Ah thanks also @Frank van Puffelen, I tried getting the key without the loop and then it would give me 'languages' instead of 'eng'. Now I understand why the loop fixes that.